# Where should I install FindXXX.cmake file of my own project and how to find it?

Tags: cmake

I am developing two CMake projects: `libABC` and `libXYZ`. `libXYZ` requires `libABC`, and so I would like install `FindABC.cmake` in an appropriate location on Mac and Linux machines.

`libABC` and its related files are installed under `/usr/local` by default, and I think `FindABC.cmake` also should be installed under the same directory. I tried installing it in the following six different locations.

`/usr/local/lib/cmake/ABC/FindABC.cmake` 
`/usr/local/share/cmake/ABC/FindABC.cmake` 
`/usr/local/lib/ABC/FindABC.cmake` 
`/usr/local/share/ABC/FindABC.cmake` 
`/usr/local/lib/ABC/cmake/FindABC.cmake` 
`/usr/local/share/ABC/cmake/FindABC.cmake`

However `CMakeList.txt` of `libXYZ` cannot find it with the following error.

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:51 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindABC.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project
  has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "ABC", but CMake did not find one.
```

My `cmake` command was installed under `/opt/local` by using MacPorts on OS X. So I think it searches not `/usr/local` but only `/opt/local`.

I know that defining `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` when executing `cmake` command solve this issue (e.g., `cmake -DCMAKE_MODULE_PATH=/usr/local/lib/cmake/ABC`), but I do not want to ask all users to do it every time.

My questions are

Q1. Where should I install `FindABC.cmake` during the `libABC` installation process?

Q2. How do I properly find `FindABC.cmake` in `CMakeLists.txt` of `libXYZ` without hard-coding `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` in it?

Comment: `FindXXX.cmake` files are provided either by CMake itself or by project, *which uses `find_package(XXX)` call*. If your ABC project want to be searched, it should install ABCConfig.cmake file instead. See description of [cmake-packaging](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-master/manual/cmake-packages.7.html) about creation such `*Config.cmake` files.

Comment: @ruso: The answer does not help here as it does not describe where to install module (findxxx.cmake) files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install your custom CMake-Find module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10765885/how-to-install-your-custom-cmake-find-module)

Comment: @ruslo: Yeah, the CMake guys which that every projects ships a config file. But in reality, there are many third party FindXXX.cmake modules.

Comment: Thank you all. I added `install(FILES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/MyProjectConfig.cmake" DESTINATION lib/cmake/MyProject COMPONENT devel)` in my `CMakeLists.txt`