# using static libraries in cmake project

Tags: c++, cmake, static-libraries

I have two C++ projects A and B. Project B depends on project A. 
Project A has this structure split into some subdirectories:

```
Project A
|-\inc
|  |-a1.h
|  |-a2.h
|-\src
   |-CMakeLists.txt
   |-\subdir_A1
   |  |-CMakeLists.txt
   |  |-a1.cpp
   |
   |-\subdir_A2
      |-CMakeLists.txt
      |-a2.cpp

Project B
|-\lib
   |-a1.h
   |-a2.h
   |-lib_ProjectA.a
|-\src
   |-CMakeLists.txt
   |-b.cpp
```

The problem is that project B can't resolve the project's A definitions. Although I've added `target_link_libraries` to CMakeLists.txt in Project B, I have an error like this:

> undefined reference to `project_a::a1::func1()"

**UPD1**

I managed to compile Project B by copping all libraries from subdirectories (liba1.a, liba2.a) and linking them to the project. I wonder if it's possible to tune Project A, so that I can do with only one file lib_ProjectA.a

**UPD2**

Code:

Project A

```
add_library (adapter
   adapter.cpp
 )

target_link_libraries (adapter PUBLIC
   net  # From project's A subdirectory 
   utils # From project's A subdirectory 
)
```

Project B

```
add_library (anthill
   functional_block.cpp)

target_link_libraries(anthill 
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/libjsoncpp.a
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/libadapter.a 
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/libnet.a     # Can't compile without it   
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/libutils.a   # Can't compile without it
)
```

Comment: Maybe setting `link_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)` in your `CMakeLists.txt` in project `B` is enough. Not sure about that, have a try and I'll add it as an answer if it solves.

Comment: Can you please show us the relevant parts of your CMake files?

Comment: @MikeMB Actually the project is much bigger and has a lot of subdirectories with other names. I'm afraid I'll make it only more confusing. Now the problem is to compile project B  without copping liba1.a and liba2.a. Is it possible?

Comment: `undefined reference` with command `target_link_libraries` means that library *has been found*, but it *doesn't define* required symbol. Something **wrong with your code**, but you don't show it. What do you expect from us?

Comment: @Tsyvarev the question isn't about my code, it's about opportunity to compile a project split into some subdirectories as a solid static library. Please, look at the update.

Comment: Thats what [mcves](/help/mcve) are for. If your project is too complex to strip it down, then create a new dummy project whith the structure in the question and try to reproduce the error there.

Comment: You may directly link to libraries within `project A`, no needs to copy them somewhere. In any case, your problem is still unclear for me. Can you provide code(simplified) which works for you, and code which you want to work?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake: Do I understand you right, that you don't build project A as part of project B?

Comment: @MikeMB Yes, you do. At first I build prorject A then copy needed files to project B. It might be useful to see  the passages from cmake files in the question's updates.

Comment: In that case you need to create a1 and a2 as [object libraries](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials/Object_Library)

Comment: @flipback For some details on "use CMake-enabled libraries in your CMake project" you may want to look at [Making cmake library accessible by other cmake packages automatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33462209/making-cmake-library-accessible-by-other-cmake-packages-automatically)

Comment: @MikeMB This is that I needed. Could you make an answer? I'd like to close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution to use [OBJECT](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials/Object_Library) option:

```
 add_library(myObjects OBJECT a.c b.c)
```