# Avoid cMake rebuild/compilation of sub project (library)

Tags: c++, cmake, project

I have a bunch of C++ source files and static libraries which form a **framework F**. To use this, I have created a main_A.cpp and some cMake files, which create an executable and run successfully (**project A**).

Now I use a different main_B.cpp for **project B**. For this I created an own cMakeLists.txt with e.g. a different executable name and which refers to the config.cmake files for **framework F**

```
framework F (global config.cmake)  
|  
|___ project A   
|  
|___ project B (own cMakeLists.txt)
```

When I compile **project B** after **project A**, all the files from **framework F** get recompiled, which takes long and is unnecessary.

*How do I get cMake to detect that framework F is already compiled when using a different projects?*

**Approach:** Create static libraries, and compile them into a common folder (lib):

```
add_library( framework STATIC ${SRC_FILES} )
set_target_properties( framework PROPERTIES LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY /lib)
```

The libraries got compiled and put into /lib but when I compile **project B**, everything gets re-compiled.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making cmake library accessible by other cmake packages automatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33462209/making-cmake-library-accessible-by-other-cmake-packages-automatically)