# Specify multiple paths in XXX_INCLUDE_DIRS or XXX_LIBRARIES of FindXXX.cmake

Tags: cmake

Consider the following example of a `FindXXX.cmake`:

```
find_path(XXX_INCLUDE_DIR NAMES XXX/XXX.h)
find_path(XXXYYY_INCLUDE_DIR NAMES YYY.h)

include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)
find_package_handle_standard_args(XXX DEFAULT_MSG
        XXX_INCLUDE_DIR XXXYYY_INCLUDE_DIR)

set(XXX_INCLUDE_DIRS "${XXX_INCLUDE_DIR} ${XXXYYY_INCLUDE_DIR}")
```

As it is in this example, `XXX_INCLUDE_DIRS` is a string with a space in the middle, and, thus, when added in `CMakeLists.txt` using

```
 target_include_directories(a PRIVATE ${XXX_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

it is invoked by the compiler as

```
-I"XXXpath XXXYYYpath"
```

How should I modify the line

```
set(XXX_INCLUDE_DIRS ${XXX_INCLUDE_DIR} ${XXXYYY_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

which sets the value for the variable `XXX_INCLUDE_DIRS`?

The same question arises for multiple library paths in `XXX_LIBRARIES`.

Comment: As a semicolon separated list? `set(xx_include_dirs "${dir_a};${dir_b})`

Comment: I also like to quote from [CMake's documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-developer.7.html#find-modules): "The traditional approach is to use variables for everything, including libraries and executables. This is what most of the existing find modules provided by CMake do. The more modern approach is to behave as much like config file packages files as possible, by providing imported target. This has the advantage of propagating Transitive Usage Requirements to consumers."

Comment: Yes, I tried (updated question). @Florian, I do not even understand what they are trying to say with that quote, sorry.

Comment: @J.C.Leitão Just that by using imported targets you could avoid such kind of problems and make it easier to use your package (see e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33462209/making-cmake-library-accessible-by-other-cmake-packages-automatically)).

Comment: Good to know about that. Unfortunately, I am not writing a package; I am writing a Find* for a dependency that I have.

Comment: It is indeed semicolon, but because of caching, the result was not being updated. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You provide multiple entries for variables like `XXX_LIBRARIES` and `XXX_INCLUDE_DIRS` as a semicolon-separated list.

```
set(XXX_INCLUDE_DIRS "${XXX_INCLUDE_DIR};${XXXYYY_INCLUDE_DIR}")
```

Comment: Your answer places all paths in one line. Can the paths be placed on different lines? Which is useful if you have many paths or long paths.

Comment: @Bart You can `set(A "${B}")`, `set(A "${A};${C}")`, `set(A "${A};${D}")` instead of `set(A "${B};${C};${D}")`

Comment: I see, it's a not an as clean solution as I had hoped for but it's better than nothing, thanks.