# How to install CMake packages (configs) globally?

Tags: c++, cmake, dependency-management

To be honest, I recently started working with find_package in CONFIG-mode... Is there an easy way to install packages globally on Windows 10?

Or I must manually set `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` and build all stuff by my hand?:

```
cmake . -Bbuild/debug -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX=d -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="install"
cmake --build build/debug --target install
cmake . -Bbuild/release -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="install"
cmake --build build/release --target install
```

All I want is - register the package once and forget about it. After the package is registered all commands like `find_package(X CONFIG REQUIRED)` must work well... Do all paths must be determined manually?

Comment: and yeah, how can I build and install release+debug using only one line command?

Comment: Do you want to install the packages or should they just be found by other CMake enabled projects? More concrete would ["Making cmake library accessible by other cmake packages automatically"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33462209/making-cmake-library-accessible-by-other-cmake-packages-automatically) be sufficient.

Comment: @Florian they must be found by other CMake-based projects without any manual path selection and etc.